# Redirect http to https does not work on subdir where another instance of WordPress installed

Tags: htaccess, https, http

I have installed two instances of WordPress, on `https://www.example.com/` and a subdirectory `https://www.example.com/blogs/`

Now to make all HTTP URLs be redirected to the HTTPS version, I add the following directive in `.htaccess` at the root folder, as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This works for all the URLs under the root folder, except those under `/blogs/` subfolder.

I try to modify the `.htaccess` under `/blogs/` by adding the above directive again. But that does not work. Why?

1. I think the directive in `.htaccess is inherited by subfolder, why it does not work for /blogs/?
2. Should I change the directive to:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blogs/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Actually I have tried to do so, but not working either.

**Update:**

Now let me provides an example to explain this more clearly:

For URL such as `http://www.example.com/outlook-repair/`, it **CAN** be redirected to the https version `https://www.example.com/outlook-repair/` properly.

However, for URL under `/blogs/` subfolder, such as `http://www.example.com/blogs/2-useful-methods-to-recover-outlook-data-from-a-damaged-disk-image-file`, it **CANNOT** be redirected to the https version, instead, what you get is still the HTTP version. That is the problem.

**Update**

Below is the `/blogs/.htaccess`, to make things simple, I have disabled the WP Fastest Cache plugin:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blogs/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blogs/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

**Update 2**

I have tried to set Redirection plugin's site options for both the main site and the blog site, as described in https://redirection.me/support/site-options/ , ubt that still does not work, either.

Comment: Please include the contents of the `/blog/.htaccess` file in your question.

Comment: @MrWhite, I have included the .htaccess, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the directive in `.htaccess` is inherited by subfolder

The mod_rewrite directives in the root `.htaccess` file are *not* inherited by the `/blog/.htaccess` file (by default). You would need to specifically enable mod_rewrite inheritance, however, this probably adds unnecessary complexity.

> I try to modify the .htaccess under /blogs/ by adding the above directive again. But that does not work. Why?

Even if mod_rewrite inheritance was enabled this would not work unaltered since it would redirect requests back to the document root. You would need to have modified the directive like you mentioned (by adding the `/blogs` subdirectory in the *substitution*), however, this would have broken the redirect for the WordPress site in the document root.

Instead, you need to repeat the HTTP to HTTPS redirect at the top of the `/blog/.htaccess` file. And since this is in a subdirectory and the subdirectory would seem to be part of the URL-path, it would be preferable to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead to avoid having to hardcode the subdirectory in the directive (although the subdirectory is hardcoded in later directives anyway - this could be avoided - but I assume is created by WordPress).

(*Aside:* If you did enable mod_rewrite inheritance you would have needed to have changed the root `.htaccess` file to also use `REQUEST_URI` instead. However, this is unlikely to be the only thing you would have needed to change.)

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full, root-relative (starting with a slash) URL-path.

The `NC` flag is superfluous here.

Comment: Thank you very much.